# Date picker not workin properly?

Tags: jquery

How to select a zebra date picker using tab key?

```
    $('#datepicker').focus(function () 
    { 
        $(this).data('Zebra_DatePicker').show(); 
    )};
```

Kindly give a solution

Comment: isn't that working? any error?

Answer (score 0):

You need to first invoke Initialize the date picker on the said element and then invoke the function to show datepicker on focus.

Although, there's a gotcha! When it shows the calendar on focus > you select a date > the element will raise 'focus' event again. So it will keep popping up until you move forward using a tab or clicking your mouse somewhere else.

Here's a solution for you:

```
var calendarShown = false;
// Initialize the date picker first

$('#datepicker').Zebra_DatePicker({    
    onSelect:function(){        
        calendarShown=false;
        $(this).data('Zebra_DatePicker').hide();
    }
});

// add an event listener to focus

$(document).on('focus','#datepicker',function(){    
    if(!calendarShown){
      $(this).data('Zebra_DatePicker').show();        
        calendarShown=true;
    }    
});
```

To avoid the problem of popping up the calendar again and again, I've added a variable **calendarShown**. On every focus it will check if the variable is false and show the calendar. On Select calendarShown again becomes false hence next time you focus, it pops up the date picker.

Here's a sample fiddle:

http://jsfiddle.net/sunnykumar08/Trr7D/

Hope it helps!